# How to put getJSON values into a variable

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to understand jQuery's getJson(). I want to put the array that it returns into a variable put I don't know how. I get undefined when I click the start button in this code. I know that everything in the PHP file works so I don't think the propblem is there.

```
function getGameData(){
var difLevel = $("input[@name=difLevel]:checked").val();
var gameData = (function(){
    var json = null;
    $.getJSON('/Spelling4/core/proof_Test_JSON_process4.php',{difNo : difLevel},function(data){
        json = data;
    });
    return json;
});

return gameData;

}
$('#startButton').click(function(e) {
    var gameData = getGameData();
    e.preventDefault();
alert(gameData[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous, when you call your function and if the  ajax request is not completed your function returns `null` you should use deferred object. Note that your attribute selector is wrong you should remove the `@`.

```
var difLevel = $("input[name=difLevel]:checked").val();
```

Comment: Why do you say I need to remove the @? It's been working fine with it so far. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON return data will end up in the json variable you specified. However, the JSON query is async so the response hasn't been returned when the getGameData() function is completed.

You need to use the JSON data within $.getJSON(...) instead of returning it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're storing a function in gamedata. You should be able to access the values with gameData()